# Create a camera that can only stay in an orbit/dome above the ground

Tags: three.js

I have a camera

```
if (srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.active) {
    srims.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.distance,
        (window.innerWidth * 0.75) / window.innerHeight,
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.minDistance,
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.maxDistance
    );

    srims.camera.position.set(
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.position.x,
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.position.y,
        srims.state.staticData.cameraSettings.position.z
    );

    srims.camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    srims.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
}
```

It works great, basically looks at 0, 0, 0 and i can orbit / zoom all the way around that target.

Let's say my scene has a floor placed on Y: 0 and we have a model on that floor and the model is 0, 0, 0.

Now the problem is, I don't want to see or go under the floor with my camera I want it to stay above Y.

Best example would be that the bounds of my camera are like a cut in half tennis ball placed on the floor. It's only above the floor, not a full ball translated half above and half below the floor.

Any examples or guidance would be great.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this as simple as preventing the camera's `position.y` value from being set below zero?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting [OrbitControls.maxPolarAngle](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxPolarAngle) to `Math.PI * 0.5`.

```js
var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );

    // controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
    
    // ambient
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    
    // light
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position.set( 20,20, 0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    // axes
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 20 ) );

    // geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 12, 8 );
    
    // material
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x00ffff, 
        flatShading: true,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );
    
    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );
    
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r112/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r112/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. Cant believe it's a 1 liner.

Comment: That's indeed great^^. Please mark the thread as answered if your problem is solved.